# HTTPPOST to LAN IP error connection refused

Tags: php, android

```
public void sendJson(final JSONObject json) {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                Log.d(null,"Sync Thread Start");
                Looper.prepare(); //For Preparing Message Pool for the child Thread
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); //Timeout Limit
                HttpResponse response;

                try {
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.2/BusTicket/sync/sync.php");

                 // Prepare JSON to send by setting the entity
                    httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json.toString(), "UTF-8"));

                    // Set up the header types needed to properly transfer JSON
                    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    response = client.execute(httpPost);

                    /*Checking response */
                    if(response!=null){
                        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); //Get the data in the entity
                        Log.d(null,"Sync Reponse= "+ convertStreamToString(in));
                        Log.d(null,"Sync Reponse= "+ in.toString() );
                    }

                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Looper.loop(); //Loop in the message queue
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }
```

### sync.php

```
<?php
echo 'hi';
?>
```

I have make my Android Device connect to Local Area Network, and i m trying to access the 192.168.1.2 web hosting server, and trying to post JSON to php server, but return following error

```
02-22 04:34:55.773: W/System.err(893): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.1.2 refused
```

But, i m trying to use my Android browser and browsing `http://192.168.1.2/BusTicket/sync/sync.php` it is working fine. WHY?

Comment: Are you sure your phone and computer using same network connection ?

Comment: @RajeshCP why not? i use Android device browser able to browse the web page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obvious it's not a router-firewall related problem as you are under the same net, so there are only a few possibilities:

- There's nothing listening on that port on that IP on the server-side
- There's a local firewall on the server-side that is blocking that connection attempt
- You are not using WIFI so you're not under the same net.

You should make sure you can open that service some ther way, that would help you debugging where the culprit is. If you've already done this, I'd suggest using some debugging tool to trace TCP packets (I don't know either what kind of operating system you use on the destination machine; if it's some linux distribution, `tcpdump` might help).

All that assuming you have the `android.permission.INTERNET` permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Thanks ! this answer are not found in google ! after i have added `android.permission.INTERNET` , it's working ! thanks buddy !

Answer (score 0):

IMO if your web server is on port 80 and your android device has a connection to YOUR WIFI , then it should work because android should use the network interface for the LAN rather than the 3G network interface.

Will not work if the network interface for 3G is being used because thre is no way for it to resolve the NAT'ed IP address  ( 192.168...)